# Notepad ++ isolate text from character x to y

Tags: notepad++

I have a file that's based around character positioning. I need to collect the values that are between column 126 and 136 to export them.

So my file will have lines like this

```
alskdfjdskfl;ja   21.32     asdlfkjasdklfsd
alskdfjdskfl;ja   976546.72 asdlfkjasdklfsd
alskdfjdskfl;ja   1027.32   asdlfkjasdklfsd
alskdfjdskfl;ja   2945.5    asdlfkjasdklfsd
alskdfjdskfl;ja   245.78    asdlfkjasdklfsd
```

The garbage characters don't matter. I just want the numbers in between. The garbage characters do not follow a specific pattern except for their placement in the line. In other words, the information I want will always start at column 126 and ends no later than 136.

Any thoughts on whether you can do this within Notepad++? Otherwise, I'll have to take another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.{125}(.{10}).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginng of line
  .{125}    : 125 any character but newline
  (         : start roup 1
    .{10}   : 10 any character but newline
  )         : end group
  .*        : 0 or more any character but newline
$           : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
```

- *check Wrap around*
- *Check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

Answer (score 0):

As long as the garbage characters aren't matched by the regex between the parentheses this could work:

`Search->Find...
Tab: Replace
Search Mode: Regular expression
Find what: .*\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+.*
Replace with: \1
[Replace All]`